# jQuery issue in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have a problem on [my website](http://www.whirlware.biz).  There a gears on the left and right sides of website, it rotates when you scroll over website. But for some reasons it does not work in Firefox and I don`t know why.

Code of rotating gears:

```
    <p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($) {
            var $gear1 = $('#gear1'),
                $gear2 = $('#gear2'),
                $gear3 = $('#gear3'),
                $gear4 = $('#gear4'),
                $body = $(document.body),
                bodyHeight = $body.height();
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                $gear1.css({
                    'transform': 'rotate(' + ($body.scrollTop() / bodyHeight * 360) + 'deg)'
                });
                $gear2.css({
                    'transform': 'rotate(' + ($body.scrollTop() / bodyHeight * -360) + 'deg)'
                });
                $gear3.css({
                    'transform': 'rotate(' + ($body.scrollTop() / bodyHeight * -360) + 'deg)'
                });
                $gear4.css({
                    'transform': 'rotate(' + ($body.scrollTop() / bodyHeight * 360) + 'deg)'
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

      </p>
     <p>
    <style scoped="scoped" type="text/css">
        .gear1 {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            position: fixed;
            top:220px;
            left:-50px;
        }
        .gear2 {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            position: fixed;
            top:310px;
            left:-50px;
        }
        .gear3 {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            position: fixed;
            top:220px;
            right:-50px;
        }
        .gear4 {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            position: fixed;
            top:310px;
            right:-50px;
        }

    </style>

    </p>
    <div class="gear1" id="gear1"><img src="images/gear.png" alt="gear" height="100" width="100" />
</div>

    <div class="gear2" id="gear2"><img src="images/gear.png" alt="gear" height="100" width="100" />
</div>

    <div class="gear3" id="gear3"><img src="images/gear.png" alt="gear" height="100" width="100" />
</div>

    <div class="gear4" id="gear4"><img src="images/gear.png" alt="gear" height="100" width="100" />
</div>
```

Comment: looks like it is only including -webkit-transform you will need the equivalent in moz and ie

Comment: @Travis - by just passing "transform" jQuery takes care of the prefixes

Answer (score 1):

Firefox uses the HTML element for the scrollbar while most other browsers uses the BODY element, so when getting the `scrollTop` it's generally a good idea to just use the window

change

```
$body.scrollTop()
```

to

```
$(window).scrollTop()
```

**EDIT:**

you could do this

```
function getScrollTop(){
    if(typeof pageYOffset!= 'undefined'){
        return pageYOffset;
    } else {
        var B = document.body;
        var D = document.documentElement;
        D = (D.clientHeight)? D: B;
        return D.scrollTop;
    }
}

jQuery(function($) {
   var $gears = $('#gear1, #gear2, #gear3, #gear4');

   $(window).on('scroll', function() { 
       var scrollTop = getScrollTop();
       $gears.css({
            'transform': 'rotate(' + (scrollTop / bodyHeight * 360) + 'deg)'
       });
   });
});
```

Comment: @user3166813 - it could be that window.scrollTop and body.scrollTop doesn't return the same value. Generally you'd position the body top left with no margins or padding and with a 100% height and width, and then it should be the same, but it the body is positioned in an other way there could be issues.

Comment: Thanks for help, I tried to use your solution but now gears are not rotate when I try to scroll

Comment: Then you'll have to console.log the values you're getting for scrollTop and the body's height, and see what the difference is.

Comment: Also, I had a stray comma causing an error in the code, that's fixed now, so try if the code works as it is now.

Comment: Maybe you know the solution that can hide gears in Firefox? I think hiding will be easier then making it works fine

Comment: It still not work... I think better way is to hide it in FF, but how?